# Compiling Qt statically on Windows XP and MinGW fail. Is it possible to achieve?

Tags: windows, qt, static, mingw

I need to compile Qt statically. I have to do it on a virtual machine running Windows XP. Because of this requirement, I can't use the PowerShell 3.0 script suggested in the wiki page [How to build a static Qt for Windows/MinGW](http://qt-project.org/wiki/How-to-build-a-static-Qt-for-Windows-MinGW) (PowerShell 3.0 can't be installed on WinXP).

I tried to read the script and do its work step by step manually.

I added to the end of `C:\Qt\5.3\Src\qtbase\mkspecs\win32-g++\qmake.conf` file:

```
# [QT-STATIC-PATCH]
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -static -static-libgcc
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE -= -O2
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE += -Os -momit-leaf-frame-pointer
DEFINES += QT_STATIC_BUILD
```

I ran the configuration:

```
mkdir C:\Qt\5.3\Static-build
cd C:\Qt\5.3\Static-build
..\Src\configure.bat -static -debug-and-release -platform win32-g++ \
-prefix C:\Qt\5.3\Static -qt-zlib -qt-pcre -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg \
-qt-freetype -opengl desktop -qt-sql-sqlite -no-openssl -opensource \
-confirm-license -make libs -nomake tools -nomake examples -nomake tests
```

and that seems OK:

```
This is the Qt for Windows Open Source Edition.

You have already accepted the terms of the license.

Creating qmake...
mingw32-make: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
Running configuration tests...
Environment:
    INCLUDE=
      Unset
    LIB=
      Unset
    PATH=
      C:\Qt\5.3\mingw482_32\bin
      C:\Qt\Tools\mingw482_32\bin
      C:\Program Files\Git\git-cheetah\..\bin
      C:\Program Files\Git\git-cheetah\..\bin
      C:\Program Files\Git\git-cheetah\..\bin
      C:\Program Files\Git\git-cheetah\..\bin
      C:\Program Files\Git\git-cheetah\..\bin
      C:\Program Files\Git\git-cheetah\..\bin
      C:\Program Files\Git\git-cheetah\..\bin
      C:\WINDOWS\system32
      C:\WINDOWS
      C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
      C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
      C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin
      C:\Program Files\CMake\bin
      C:\Python27
      C:\StrawberryPerl\perl\bin
      C:\StrawberryPerl\win32
      C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
Configuration:
    pcre
    debug
    compile_examples
Qt Configuration:
    minimal-config
    small-config
    medium-config
    large-config
    full-config
    debug_and_release build_all release
    debug
    c++11
    static
    zlib
    gif
    jpeg
    png
    freetype
    build_all
    accessibility
    opengl
    audio-backend
    native-gestures
    qpa
    iconv
    concurrent

QMAKESPEC...................win32-g++ (commandline)
Architecture................i386, features:
Host Architecture...........i386, features:
Maketool....................mingw32-make
Debug build.................yes (combined)
Default build...............debug
Force debug info............no
C++11 support...............yes
Link Time Code Generation...no
Accessibility support.......yes
RTTI support................yes
SSE2 support................yes
SSE3 support................yes
SSSE3 support...............yes
SSE4.1 support..............yes
SSE4.2 support..............yes
AVX support.................yes
AVX2 support................yes
NEON support................no
IWMMXT support..............no
OpenGL support..............yes
Large File support..........yes
NIS support.................no
Iconv support...............yes
Evdev support...............no
Mtdev support...............no
Inotify support.............no
eventfd(7) support..........no
Glib support................no
CUPS support................no
OpenVG support..............no
OpenSSL support.............no
Qt D-Bus support............no
Qt Widgets module support...yes
Qt GUI module support.......yes
QML debugging...............yes
DirectWrite support.........no
Use system proxies..........no

QPA Backends:
    GDI.....................yes
    Direct2D................no

Third Party Libraries:
    ZLIB support............qt
    GIF support.............yes
    JPEG support............yes
    PNG support.............yes
    FreeType support........yes
    Fontconfig support......no
    HarfBuzz-NG support.....no
    PCRE support............qt
    ICU support.............no
    ANGLE...................no
    Dynamic OpenGL..........no

Styles:
    Windows.................yes
    Windows XP..............yes
    Windows Vista...........yes
    Fusion..................yes
    Windows CE..............no
    Windows Mobile..........no

Sql Drivers:
    ODBC....................no
    MySQL...................no
    OCI.....................no
    PostgreSQL..............no
    TDS.....................no
    DB2.....................no
    SQLite..................yes (qt)
    SQLite2.................no
    InterBase...............no

Sources are in..............C:\Qt\5.3\Src\qtbase
Build is done in............C:\Qt\5.3\Static-build\qtbase
Install prefix..............C:\Qt\5.3\Static
Headers installed to........C:\Qt\5.3\Static\include
Libraries installed to......C:\Qt\5.3\Static\lib
Arch-dep. data to...........C:\Qt\5.3\Static
Plugins installed to........C:\Qt\5.3\Static\plugins
Library execs installed to..C:\Qt\5.3\Static\bin
QML1 imports installed to...C:\Qt\5.3\Static\imports
QML2 imports installed to...C:\Qt\5.3\Static\qml
Binaries installed to.......C:\Qt\5.3\Static\bin
Arch-indep. data to.........C:\Qt\5.3\Static
Docs installed to...........C:\Qt\5.3\Static\doc
Translations installed to...C:\Qt\5.3\Static\translations
Examples installed to.......C:\Qt\5.3\Static\examples
Tests installed to..........C:\Qt\5.3\Static\tests
WARNING: Using static linking will disable the use of plugins.
         Make sure you compile ALL needed modules into the library.

Generating Makefiles...


Qt is now configured for building. Just run mingw32-make.
To reconfigure, run mingw32-make confclean and configure.
```

But the compilation with mingw32-make failed at some point:

```
cd qml/ && ( test -e Makefile || c:/Qt/5.3/Static-build/qtbase/bin/qmake.exe C:/Qt/5.3/Src/qtdeclarative/tools/qml/qml.pro -o
 Makefile ) && c:/Qt/Tools/mingw482_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile
'QT_PLUGIN_PATH' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.
Project ERROR: Failed to parse qmlimportscanner output.
Makefile:94: recipe for target 'sub-qml-make_first' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [sub-qml-make_first] Error 3
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'c:/Qt/5.3/Static-build/qtdeclarative/tools'
Makefile:66: recipe for target 'sub-tools-make_first' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [sub-tools-make_first] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'c:/Qt/5.3/Static-build/qtdeclarative'
Makefile:101: recipe for target 'module-qtdeclarative-make_first' failed
mingw32-make: *** [module-qtdeclarative-make_first] Error 2
```

Sorry for the french wording. The interesting point is:

> 'QT_PLUGIN_PATH' is not recognized as internal or external command, an executable program or a command file

I found other people having the same issue ([here](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/38552)) and tried the solution they suggested (from [here](https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages/blob/master/mingw-w64-qt5/qt-5.3.0-static-qmake-conf.patch)):

I added

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS_STATIC_LIB += -static
```

to qtbase/mkspecs/win32-g++/qmake.conf and added

```
static:win32: QMAKE_LFLAGS += $$QMAKE_LFLAGS_STATIC_LIB
```

to qtbase/mkspecs/features/default_post.prf

I still have the error.

So I have 2 questions:

1. **Do you know if it is possible to compile Qt 5.3 on Windows XP with MinGW?**
2. **Does someone know how to fix the error `'QT_PLUGIN_PATH' is not recognized [...]`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for a weird reason, after closing my console, re-opening it and re-trying, it worked :/ I leave this question open in case that someone have a better explanation for "'QT_PLUGIN_PATH' is not recognized [...]" error. Apparently I was not the first to get stuck on this error.